# How to autohide TabLayout in on Scrollup/Scrolldown

Tags: android-studio, material-design, android-appbarlayout

After going through lot of tutorials for auto hiding toolbar/tabbar. i came across material design support library in which we can autohide toolbar/tabbar easily using this:

app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"  (In XML toolbar)
 This is support Library reference 
        --> compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

But what I need is to autohide the TabLayout(Tabbar and not Toolbar) on scrollup and showback TabLayout on scrolling down.

This is my activity_main.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/id_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

I checked adding  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" in TabLayout, but its not working. Can anybody help me in achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my codes:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_coordinator_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:paddingEnd="0dp"
        app:paddingStart="0dp">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_appcompat"></include>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
            style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabContentStart="2dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMinWidth="24dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabPadding="1dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:paddingEnd="0dp"
        app:paddingStart="0dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_toggle"
        app:borderWidth="1dp"
        app:elevation="3dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/home_coordinator_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="2dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/swipe_refresh_color_scheme_green" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It works well. It will hide when `ViewPager` is scrolled up and will show when `ViewPager` is scrolled down.

Comment: First thanks for immediate response, I tried with your code, its not autohiding Tabbar on scrollup/down. Can you be more specific on TabLayout and convey what changes i have to make there.